# Unhandled Error: Cannot convert 'document.getElementById(punkte_liste_titel_user)' to object

Tags: javascript, object, getelementbyid

I have a html page (partly generated with PHP), and I have a JavaScript file included at the bottom of the page that provides some onclick functions. I was struggling to get the variables from PHP to JS, so I created two `<span>`s with unique ids and put the content of the variables there (numeric/int values). My idea was to use `var php_get_userid = document.getElementById(punkte_liste_titel_user).innerHTML;` to have JS read the values into variables, and then use them.
However the getElementById doesn't work although the `<span>` with the corresponding ID definitly does exist. In Opera it says

> Unhandled Error: Cannot convert
>   'document.getElementById(punkte_liste_titel_user)' to object

Chrome says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

The HTML of the area looks like this

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="punkte_liste_titel">
        Points <span id="punkte_liste_titel_datum">20130901</span>/<span id="punkte_liste_titel_user">3</span>
        </div> <!-- Ende Punkteliste -->
        <div id="punkte_liste">
...
```

the JS starts like this

```
$('.punkte_kategorie_element').click(function() {
    var php_get_userid = document.getElementById(punkte_liste_titel_user).innerHTML;
    var php_get_datum = document.getElementById(punkte_liste_titel_datum).innerHTML;
...
```

the JavaScript file is included right before the `</body>` tag

I tried to create a minimal version of this at http://jsfiddle.net/WRfh5/2/ which doesn't run either... what am I missing?

Comment: I found a way around this problem by appending the two variables to the id of the clickable element so that i can use `var id_and_variables = $(this).attr("id");` and then split to get the values. It works but feels like a not-too-clever hack. And I still don't understand the problem with the original way at all...

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to enclose id in quotes

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

```
document.getElementById('punkte_liste_titel_user').
                        ^                       ^
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WRfh5/3/)